# Не работает bootstrap accordion на React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap

Пишу SSR приложение на next

Установил React bootstrap чтоб использовать его компоненты

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@5.0.2
```

[Согласно документации](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/) использую подключение

```
import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
```

И сам код

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #2</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
```

Код не работает и выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если использовать такой код то все работает. Но мне надо класический accordion bootstrap где есть шефрон открытый или закрытый accordion, где название accordion не является кнопкой

```
 <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
    <Card>
      <Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} 
          variant="link" eventKey="0">
          Click Me to Toggle!
        </Accordion.Toggle>
      </Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
        <Card.Body>
         Greetings from GeeksforGeeks
        </Card.Body>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
  </Accordion>
```